# How to refer to a multi-field index in indexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I created an index on two fields combined in indexedDB as follows:

```
objectStore.createIndex(["B", "E"], ["B", "E"], {unique:false});
```

The indexedDB and key look fine when I view them in the Chrome developer tools.

The problem is later when I get ready to do a transaction, I'm not sure how to refer to this index.  The console lists it's name as "B,E" but this results in an error:

```
var index = objectStore.index("B,E");
```

returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined at IDBOpenDBRequest.openRequest.onsuccess
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `createIndex` is a simple string that gives a name to the index that you can then refer to. The second argument is the key path.

Try `createIndex('myBEIndex', ['B', 'E'], ...)` to create it with the name and later use `store.index('myBEIndex')` to refer to it by name.

Comment: Please edit your question to include in your code how you define the variable `objectStore`

Comment: Hmm... I tried this and got the error. I created the index as `keyPath = ["B", "E"]; objectStore.createIndex("BE", keyPath, {unique:false});` and then tried to refer to it as var index = objectStore.index("BE"); and got the error: `content.js:147 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'index' on 'IDBObjectStore': The specified index was not found at IDBOpenDBRequest.openRequest.onsuccess`

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the error I received in the prior comment.  These are the two lines in my `openRequest.onsuccess` function that trigger the error in my last comment: `var objectStore = transaction.objectStore("hcLookup"); var index = objectStore.index("BE");`

Comment: OK, got it to work.  It seems the error is that you can't use a variable in referring to an index?  I had this, which triggered the error: `var index = objectStore.index("BE");  objectStore.index(index).openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(event) {...`   It worked when I changed it to this:  `var index = objectStore.index("BE");  objectStore.index("BE").openCursor(range).onsuccess = function(event) {...`

Comment: My guess is that you were not causing a database upgrade by changing version? onupgradeneeded, where the createIndex call occurs, only runs when you increment the version (the second parameter to indexedDB.open).